# Start all the time with ALT+CTRL+F1|F2|F3...|F6

Tags: lubuntu, console

when the desktop starts and my `lubuntu` loads, i can press `ALT+CTRL+F2` to use console only without windows or taskbar.

It's possible to force only this console mode ? i just want to use a console

What is the advantages? It starts only faster?
The disadvantages? Some usefuls process don't start (like `ssh-server`?) ?

I use `lubuntu` because it's more ligher than `ubuntu`, but is there any difference between `lubuntu-console-only` and `ubuntu-console-only` ?

Thanks

---

EDIT#1: My actual `/etc/default/grub` file

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text nogpumanager"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter t Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"` not working

Comment: im pretty sure that you need to remove quiet and splash so your line should read `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` im testing it now on a vm

Comment: ok . .tested it out and even with quiet and splash removed I seem to have the same problem .. still boots to the gui so I guess I was wrong .. disregard my comments :D

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the post listed by Byte Commander .. I have just tried all the solutions and none of them work so this is a still unanswered question

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. The answer of @ByteCommander not work. Maybe `ubuntu` is different than `lubuntu` on boot?

Comment: I take that back the entry that says `For systems that use systemd` that says to run `sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force` and 
`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` did work so I guess yeah this is a duplicate or at least that worked for me .. im now in a text only boot

Comment: And my other three questions? :p I have to create new questions?

Comment: it would probably be better to start a new question .. I really don't know what the difference is between the consoles and as far as I know the ssh server should start